# How can I debug my tests in Open Liberty server dev mode (using liberty-maven-plugin) and toggle the debugger on/off?

Tags: websphere, websphere-liberty, open-liberty, liberty-maven-plugin

### SUMMARY

How can I iteratively run my unit/integration tests in ["dev mode"](https://openliberty.io/blog/2019/10/22/liberty-dev-mode.html) of the liberty-maven-plugin and easily turn on and off the launching of the debugger into the JVM running the tests themselves?

#### BACKGROUND

While the liberty-maven-plugin by default starts the Open Liberty server in debug mode, sometimes you need to debug into the source of the unit/integration tests themselves.   The liberty-maven-plugin dev mode launches the server and will (by default) run my tests each time I hit `<Enter>`.

I can leverage standard [documented](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/debugging.html) approaches, which by default will launch a forked JVM waiting for a debugger on port 5005, e.g.:

```sh
mvn -Dmaven.failsafe.debug liberty:dev
```

But what if I already started dev mode without that property set on the command line?

Is there an easy way to enable the debugger after the fact?   Or to toggle it on/off across executions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to "toggle" the debug mode for the tests is to use Maven project properties and dynamically comment/uncomment out the standard test debug properties, e.g. **maven.failsafe.debug**.

E.g this will launch ITs in a forked JVM, suspended and waiting for the debugger on port 5005:

```xml
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.failsafe.debug>true</maven.failsafe.debug>
        <!-- 
          <maven.surefire.debug>true</maven.surefire.debug>
        -->
    </properties>
```

You can also configure the maven-failsafe-plugin in your pom.xml with normal plugin configuration to configure non-default behavior.

This should work with recent (since v3.1) versions of the liberty-maven-plugin, e.g.:

```xml
        <plugin>
            <groupId>io.openliberty.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>liberty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.3</version>
        </plugin>
```

This could be applied to a simple sample app like the one here:
https://openliberty.io/guides/getting-started.html

#### WARNING

Don't make the mistake of toggling the value to "false" since you're really configuring [this](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html#debugForkedProcess) parameter.  Just comment it out completely to avoid suspending for the debugger.